# Networking - how to allow from second lan interface to access first lan interface?

Tags: 14.04, networking, lan, ip, intranet

I have one box with 2 ethernet interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.2.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  #network 192.168.1.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  #broadcast 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 195.130.131.11 192.130.130.139
```

Now eth0 is connected to main internet
and eth1 is connected with another laptop Windows 7 which has ip : 192.168.2.2

But Windows 7 cant ping my eth0 IP. How can i make it possible?

Comment: Hi there! Could you add more in detail please? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Does that mean its a direct connect between windows 7 and eth1? If so, why?... Also your eth1 IP looks same as your router IP... Need some more info to assist better!

Comment: @AzkerM: YES windows 7 directly connected to eth1 and windows 7 i have ip 192.168.2.2. But Ubuntu cant ping Windows 7 and Windows 7 cant ping Ubuntu. I want to access Ubuntu eth0 and eth1 via Windows 7 (without using any switch hardwares just straight cable)

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/551010/nat-rules-betweek-2-network-interfaces-with-iptables

Comment: Refer the links given by @bodhi.zazen... That should help you

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: i tried you suggested links but see in ubuntu 14.04 they are not anymore working: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8201667/

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 they are not working anymore, if i tried bodhi.zazen suggestion in older Ubuntu they works but not in 3.13.0-32-generic. Please advise.

Comment: You need to post your configuration files and what you did. The same instructions still work.